# In Node.js how can I tell the path of `this` module?

Tags: javascript, path, node.js

In a Node.js module I would like to open a file--i.e, with `fs.readFile()`--that is contained in the same directory as my module. By which I mean it is in the same directory as the `./node_modules/<module_name>/index.js` file.

It looks like all relative path operations which are performed by the `fs` module take place relative to the directory in which Node.js is started. As such, I think I need to know how to get the path of the current Node.js module which is executing.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `__dirname` and `__filename` to get information about the location of the module.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As david van brink mentioned in the comments, the correct solution is to use `__dirname`. This global variable will return the path of the currently executing script (i.e. you might need to use `../` to reach the root of your module).

For example:

```
var path = require("path");
require(path.join(__dirname, '/models'));
```

Just to save someone from a headache.

Comment: I can't get this to work for me. Calling `__dirname` from the code in a module inside `node_modules`, when ran by the importing script, gives me the path to the importing script's dir. I.e. no path to my package inside `node_modules`.