# Determining Paths for Loaded Modules in Node.js

Tags: javascript, python, module, node.js, commonjs

In Node.js, is there any way to determine where on the filesystem a module was loaded from?

I do **NOT** mean, what directory context Node.js is executing in--which you can determine with `process.cwd()`. I want to know something specific about whatever module is in memory.

For instance, in Python I can do the following...

```
>>> import os
>>> os.__file__
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/os.pyc'
```

Which shows me where on the filesystem the `os` module is from. Is there anyway to do something similar in Node.js?

---

**NOTE:** I was trying to ask this question when I asked my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215871/in-node-js-how-can-i-tell-the-path-of-this-module), but I phrased it poorly and ended up getting an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use require.resolve('module_name')

Comment: I think that is subtly different from my question in that it will tell you what file 'would be' loaded for a given module name, instead of allowing you to determine what file was loaded for a given module. But it certainly works for my purposes! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the require.resolve(...) function to get what you are looking for.