# How can I get the path of a module I have loaded via require that is *not* mine (i.e. in some node_module)

Tags: node.js

I require a module that was installed via npm. I want to access a .js file subordinate to that module (so I can subclass a Constructor method in it). I can't (well, don't want to) modify the module's code, so don't have a place to extract its __dirname.

I am aware of the following question, but it is about getting the path of a module that one has code control over (hence, __dirname is the solution):
[In Node.js how can I tell the path of `this` module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215871/in-node-js-how-can-i-tell-the-path-of-this-module)

~~~

Even better would be to get the module's loaded module info

Comment: where you able to load the module without any error with require('modulename')?

Comment: can you explain it better? some code?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you should use [require.resolve()](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options):

> Use the internal require() machinery to look up the location of a module, but rather than loading the module, just return the resolved filename.

Example: `var pathToModule = require.resolve('module');`

Comment: This answer doesn't work reliably with all node modules.  See my answer.

Comment: This answer does not work for me, see @Jason's answer.

Comment: `ReferenceError: require is not defined` in esm, how to solve it in esm ?

Answer (score 135):

[require.resolve()](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve) is a partial answer. The accepted answer may work for many node modules, but won't work for all of them.

`require.resolve("moduleName")` doesn't give you the directory where the module is installed; it gives you the location of the file defined in the `main` attribute in the module's `package.json`.

That might be *`moduleName/index.js`* or it could be *`moduleName/lib/moduleName.js`*.  In the latter case, `path.dirname(require.resolve("moduleName"))` will return a directory you may not want or expect: *`node_modules/moduleName/lib`*

The correct way to get the complete path to a specific module is by resolving the filename:

```
let readmePath = require.resolve("moduleName/README.md");
```

If you just want the directory for the module (maybe you're going to make a lot of `path.join()` calls), then resolve the `package.json` — which must always be in the root of the project — and pass to `path.dirname()`:

```
let packagePath = path.dirname(require.resolve("moduleName/package.json"));
```

Comment: very clever answer, by detecting the `package.json` file. Shouldn't you use `path.join('moduleName', 'package.json')` for being Windows compatible?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira `require.resolve` is platform agnostic, just like `require` so it is not needed to use `path.join`

Comment: Don't forget to add `const path = require('path');` before using `path.dirname`.

Comment: I wish this answer was fully true! I can successfully resolve something like `require.resolve('@scope/module')` which gives me something like `/path/to/@scope/module/dist/index.js`, however if I try to run `require.resolve('@scope/module/package.json')` it throws a `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error. I'm in Node 14.4.0, and the module I am trying to resolve has `"type": "module"` in its package.json with an `exports` field that does not include `package.json`. Not sure if that has anything to do with it...

Comment: I found the problem: when a module has `type: module`, apparently `package.json` has to be explicitly exposed in the `exports` field. I thought that Node's new ESM feature didn't not block `require` from resolving paths like usual, but apparent it does.

Comment: @trusktr we have scoping in APIs because we want to reserve options on what to expose, alter, or remove in the future. Node seems to be missing some basic metadata functionality around for pulling package metadata, which really should be a feature IMO.
The only other suggestion I have is to look at the pkginfo module, which assumes that the main is a child of the module folder and traverses up until it finds it.  https://github.com/indexzero/node-pkginfo/blob/master/lib/pkginfo.js#L89 You're probably right about resolve-package-path, rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Does not work for monorepos, `package.json` is not "always be in the root of the project"

Comment: Ultimately this is all about trying to peak at files in other projects that the projects did not predict you wanting to peak at.  There are going to be diminishing returns and at some point you'll have to start scanning the filesystem based off of the resolve path.  Probably using the resolve-package-path tool mentioned by trusktr

Comment: @Blunderchips the problem with your suggested edit is that the question is 'how to find the path of the module', not 'how to find the path to a file in the module'. In my case for instance I'm hunting for a config directory (for node-config), no two of which are guaranteed to contain the same filename. You can't resolve a path, only files

Comment: "which must always be in the root of the project" is simply incorrect.

Comment: Except you didn't delete that part, you deleted all of the code for the solution

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that returns the module directory in a platform agnostic way. This does not use any 3rd party libraries and successfully locates ESM modules with `"type": "module"` and modules installed via `npm link`..

> **NOTE:** If a particular module is a symlink to another location (eg. `npm link`) you will need use `fs.realpath` to get the location of the target directory:
>
> ```js
> const moduleDir = getModuleDir('some-npm-module');
> const theRealPath = fs.realpathSync(moduleDir);
> ```

#### ESM

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { createRequire } from 'module';

/**
 * Get's the file path to a module folder.
 * @param {string} moduleEntry 
 * @param {string} fromFile 
 */
const getModuleDir = (moduleEntry) => {
    const packageName = moduleEntry.includes('/') 
        ? moduleEntry.startsWith('@') 
            ? moduleEntry.split('/').slice(0, 2).join('/') 
            : moduleEntry.split('/')[0]
        : moduleEntry;
    const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
    const lookupPaths = require.resolve.paths(moduleEntry).map((p) => path.join(p, packageName));
    return lookupPaths.find((p) => fs.existsSync(p)); 
};
```

#### CommonJS

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { createRequire } = require('module');

/**
 * Get's the file path to a module's folder.
 * @param {string} moduleEntry 
 * @param {string} fromFile 
 */
const getModuleDir = (moduleEntry, relativeToFile = __filename) => {
    const packageName = moduleEntry.includes('/') 
        ? moduleEntry.startsWith('@') 
            ? moduleEntry.split('/').slice(0, 2).join('/') 
            : moduleEntry.split('/')[0]
        : moduleEntry;
    const require = createRequire(relativeToFile);
    const lookupPaths = require.resolve.paths(moduleEntry).map((p) => path.join(p, packageName));
    return lookupPaths.find((p) => fs.existsSync(p)); 
};
```

Comment: This may not work for linked dependencies.

Comment: In fact, the whole beauty of this solution is that it uses the internal mechanisms of `require.resolve` and `import.meta.resolve` to find the actual file path to a module. There is nothing special or hackish going on, and it works with ESM modules, and it doesn't require 3rd party modules... unlike every other solution offered in this thread (as of this writing).

Comment: You can't assume `entry` to contain `moduleName`. I.e. the linked dependency may not contain `moduleName` in its filesystem path, which is usually the case for scoped npm package names e.g. `@brillout/json-s`.

Comment: @brillout - you are absolutely correct. Thanks for pointing out my oversight. I've updated my answer to reflect this. I still find this useful as it's a 4 line function that satisfies 90% of use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply & udpate. I removed my down-vote. One more thing: I wonder if this works with Yarn PnP?

Comment: I don't have much experience with PnP, but based on [this page (near the bottom)](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp), it sounds like they patch node's `fs` and `require.resolve` to load files directly from the zip archive... so my guess would be that my code should still work - but that is not tested and I'm not in a position to learn and test.

Comment: Also, this won't work if the dependency has no `main` entry. (I.e. you must know an entry.)

Comment: @brillout - thanks again for the comment. I've updated the answer to indicate that a valid entry point must be used. I also updated the code to 1) detemine the package name from a nested entry point and 2) use `createRequire` so that it works in both CJS and ESM environments without any flags.

Comment: @brillout - I have further refined this method to now work with symlinks (`npm link`, et al), scoped module names, nested module entry points, and global packages. Let me know if you can poke any more holes in it.

Comment: Neat, although this solution still needs the npm package to have a `package.json#main` entry (or `package.json#exports["./"]`).

Comment: I've made some updates since my last comment. By using `require.resolve.paths`, I'm able to locate modules no matter the main/exports value in package.json. This also works for link'd modules (npm link, pnpm, etc). Users can pass a module name or a nested entry point, and we will discover the module's location by its package name.

Comment: Ok, I see. Neat idea to use `require.resolve.paths(request)`. One problem though: unlike `require.resolve(request, options)` it doesn't accept `options.paths` so it only works if you want to resolve the npm package starting from `__dirname` which makes this solution not work in certain situations.

Answer (score 5):

Jason's answer was the best answer, until Node.js ESM and the `exports` field came out.

Now that Node supports packages with an `exports` field that by default will *prevent files like `package.json` from being resolvable* unless the package author explicitly decides to expose them, the trick in Jason's answer will fail for packages that do not explicitly expose `package.json`.

There is a package called [`resolve-package-path`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-package-path) that does the trick.

Here's how to use it:

```js
const resolvePkg = require('resolve-package-path')

console.log(resolvePkg('@some/package'))
```

which will output something like

```
/path/to/@some/package/package.json
```

regardless of what the package's `exports` field contains.

Comment: I suspect that once an author is consciously exporting part of the contents of the module, you are on even shakier ground, because now the author has formally defined their public interface.  That would, I think, tend to result in more aggressive refactoring of things that are not explicitly exported, would it not?

Comment: @Jason That's true for the source files, but package.json files aren't going away. I don't see any reason those should be hidden from import.

Comment: If you're specifically looking for package.json instead of the other files, then yes, but that's only one flavor of the question at hand. Really I think we should all be pushing for the module object to contain the contents of the package.json file so we don't have to do stupid stuff like this anymore.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, `require.resolve` returns the module identifier according to CommonJS. In node.js this is the filename. In **webpack** this is a number.

In **webpack** situation, here is my solution to find out the module path:

```
const pathToModule = require.resolve('module/to/require');
console.log('pathToModule is', pathToModule); // a number, eg. 8
console.log('__webpack_modules__[pathToModule] is', __webpack_modules__[pathToModule]);
```

Then from `__webpack_modules__[pathToModule]` I got information like this:

```
(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    eval("module.exports = (__webpack_require__(6))(85);\n\n//////////////////\n// 
    WEBPACK FOOTER\n// delegated ./node_modules/echarts/lib/echarts.js from dll-reference vendor_da75d351571a5de37e2e\n// module id = 8\n// module chunks = 0\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///delegated_./node_modules/echarts/lib/echarts.js_from_dll-reference_vendor_da75d351571a5de37e2e?");

    /***/
})
```

Turned out I required old scripts from previous dll build file(for faster build speed), so that my updated module file didn't work as I expected. Finally I rebuilt my dll file and solved my problem.

Ref: [Using `require.resolve` to get resolved file path (node)](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1554)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I correctly understand your needs: to get entry point file of some module. Let's say you want to get entry point of `jugglingdb` module:

```
node
> require('module')._resolveFilename('jugglingdb')
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jugglingdb/index.js'
```

As you can see this is not "official" way to get this kind of information about module, so behavior of this function may change from version to version. I've found it in node source: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L280

Answer (score 1):

According to @anatoliy solution,  On MacOS X I have found the lookup paths doing

```
require('module')._resolveLookupPaths('myModule')
```

so I get the resolved lookup paths

```
[ 'myModule',
  [ '/Users/admin/.node_modules',
    '/Users/admin/.node_libraries',
    '/usr/local/lib/node' ] ]
```

whereas the

```
require('module')._resolveFilename('myModule')
```

will not resolve the module I was looking for anyways, in fact the crazy thing is that the `_load` will not resolve the module:

```
> require('module')._load('myModule')
Error: Cannot find module 'myModule'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at repl:1:19
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:32:31)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:31:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:308:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:489:10)
```

while the `require` will:

```
> require('myModule')
```

but I don't have this module in

```
myProject/node_modules/
myProject/node_modules/@scope/
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@scope
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@scope
$HOME/.npm/
$HOME/.npm/@scope/
```

so where is this module???

First I had to do a `$ sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`
Then after some coffee I did `locate myModule` or better `locate myModule/someFile.js`

et voilà, it comes out that it was in a parent folder of my project i.e. outside my project root folder:

```
$pwd
/Users/admin/Projects/Node/myProject
$ ls ../../node_modules/myModule/
```

so you cannot avoid to `rm -rf ../../node_modules/myModule/` and a fresh `npm install`.

I can argue that no one instructed `npm` to scan my computer in search for modules elsewhere than my project root folder where it was supposed to run or in the default modules search path.

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe what you're looking for, check:

> require.main.filename

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

First get the module main file path:

```
const mainDir = require.resolve(moduleName);
```

which output: D:\app\node_modules\tinycolor2\cjs\tinycolor.js

Then, get the package dir:

```
const realDir = mainDir.substring(0,mainDir.indexOf(moduleName)+moduleName.length);
```

Output: D:\app\node_modules\tinycolor2

Answer (score 0):

### ESM Solution

While this does not directly get the **folder**, it will get you the **entry point** (whatever is written down under `exports`, or `main` (if `exports` is missing))

You can use `import.meta.resolve("foreignModule")` to get the entry point.
The returned object is a FileURL. So you can use `fileURLToPath` from `url` to convert it into a regular path.

#### Repro:

```
npm init -y;
npm pkg set type="module";
npm i chalk;
```

```js
// index.js

import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

const pathToModuleEntry = fileURLToPath(import.meta.resolve("chalk"));
console.log(pathToModuleEntry);
// your/path/to/dir/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js
```

For reference, an excerpt from chalk's `package.json`:

```json
{
    ...
    "type": "module",
    "main": "./source/index.js",
    "exports": "./source/index.js",
    "imports": {
     ...
    },
    "types": "./source/index.d.ts",
    ...
}
```