# How to use npm-installed bootstrap in express?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I 'm a beginner of Node.js development,
Now I try to use bootstrap framework in my first Express web app.

I use

```
npm install bootstrap
```

to download the files,and it seems that npm puts them in my node_modules folder.

My question is how can I refer to the bootstrap files in my views in express?

I know a typical way is copying the bootstrap file into the public folder. So my html files can find them. But I don't think this is a good idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reference it in the `<script>` and `<link>` tags in the header or at the bottom of your main script.

If you're using express, you're probably using templating. To use it in your header part or in your main template (depending on how you've managed your views) like :

```
<script language="javascript" src="node_modules/bootstrap/.../bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/.../bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

This works only if you didn't moved your files with a gulp or a grunt task

Comment: Even better, use the output of [`require.resolve()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10121471/5513988) as the path with your view engine.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? `node_modules` folder is not visible for the browser in a standard express setup.

Answer (score 50):

You need to use in your server.js:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist'));
```

to define a static resourse and then use:

```
<script language="javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Comment: you may want to add a [virtual path prefix](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for your static like: 
    `app.use("/bootstrap", express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')));`

Comment: I found a similar question. In which the solution is explained better by @augusto-goncalves. His solution works for me. It is similar to the solution above but more elaborated and clears confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a way to transpile scss in express using node sass middleware, for example https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware.

That way you can override bootstrap scss. You can do the same for JS with webpack: transpile client-side js and then include the bundle.js in your frontend.