# Node.js. How to get a path to imported file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, path

I'm writing a parser and i'm getting imports like `../modules/greeting.js`, also i have an absolute path to file (from where i have done an import) - for instance `C:\Desktop\Folder\src\scripts\main.js`.

How to get path to file which i have imported? (in this case it should be `src/modules/greeting.js`). Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In node.JS how can I get the path of a module I have loaded via require that is \*not\* mine (i.e. in some node\_module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111163/in-node-js-how-can-i-get-the-path-of-a-module-i-have-loaded-via-require-that-is)

Comment: No, i just have strings (with paths i have described above). I'm writing on bundle side so it has nothing to do with client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for the absolute path to the imported file:

```
path.resolve(path.dirname('C:\\Desktop\\Folder\\src\\scripts\\main.js'), '../modules/greeting.js')
```

Returns: "C:\Desktop\Folder\src\modules\greeting.js"
Check the API docs for more path utils: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html